# Simplify code by finding a way to remove many if statements

Tags: javascript, c++, c, glsl, webgl

I'm having trouble figuring out a good way to structure my code. I am writing a shader in GLSL. I'm using WebGL. So I have a sprite sheet with 22 items. The sheet is 640 X 640. Except for the last each row has 5 sprites. So I used the following code just to test things out.

```
float positionInTime = (currentAge / duration);
positionInTime /= 0.04545;
positionInTime = sign(positionInTime)*floor(abs(positionInTime)+0.5);
vec2 TextureCoord = vec2( 0.0, 0.0 );

if ( positionInTime == 22.0) {
   TextureCoord = vec2( 0.0, 0.0 ); 
}
if ( positionInTime == 21.0) {
   TextureCoord = vec2( 0.2, 0.0 ); 
}
if ( positionInTime == 20.0) {
   TextureCoord = vec2( 0.4, 0.0 ); 
}
if ( positionInTime == 19.0) {
   TextureCoord = vec2( 0.6, 0.0 ); 
}
if ( positionInTime == 18.0) {
   TextureCoord = vec2( 0.8, 0.0 ); 
}
if ( positionInTime == 17.0) {
   TextureCoord = vec2( 0.0, 0.2 ); 
}
if ( positionInTime == 16.0) {
   TextureCoord = vec2( 0.2, 0.2 ); 
}
if ( positionInTime == 15.0) {
   TextureCoord = vec2( 0.4, 0.2 ); 
}
if ( positionInTime == 14.0) {
   TextureCoord = vec2( 0.6, 0.2 ); 
}
if ( positionInTime == 13.0) {
   TextureCoord = vec2( 0.8, 0.2 ); 
}
if ( positionInTime == 12.0) {
   TextureCoord = vec2( 0.0, 0.4 ); 
}
if ( positionInTime == 11.0) {
   TextureCoord = vec2( 0.2, 0.4 ); 
}
if ( positionInTime == 10.0) {
   TextureCoord = vec2( 0.4, 0.4 ); 
}
if ( positionInTime == 9.0) {
   TextureCoord = vec2( 0.6, 0.4 ); 
}
if ( positionInTime == 8.0) {
   TextureCoord = vec2( 0.8, 0.4 ); 
}
if ( positionInTime == 7.0) {
   TextureCoord = vec2( 0.0, 0.6 ); 
}
if ( positionInTime == 6.0) {
   TextureCoord = vec2( 0.2, 0.6 ); 
}
if ( positionInTime == 5.0) {
   TextureCoord = vec2( 0.4, 0.6 ); 
}
if ( positionInTime == 4.0) {
   TextureCoord = vec2( 0.6, 0.6 ); 
}
if ( positionInTime == 3.0) {
   TextureCoord = vec2( 0.8, 0.8 ); 
}
if ( positionInTime == 2.0) {
   TextureCoord = vec2( 0.0, 0.8 ); 
}
if ( positionInTime == 1.0) {
   TextureCoord = vec2( 0.2, 0.8 ); 
}

vec2 TextureSize = vec2(.2, .2);
mediump vec2 realTexCoord = TextureCoord + (gl_PointCoord * TextureSize);
vec4 rotatedTexture = texture2D( texture, realTexCoord );
gl_FragColor = rotatedTexture;
```

}

The code works but I'd like to improve upon it. It seems like these if states could be greatly simplified by a for loop. Any one have any ideas? Or if 2 variables could be created for TextureCoord x and y that would be great.

Comment: Why do you need a loop? Can't you just calculate the two parameters numerically from the `positionInTime` value?

Comment: It could be greatly improved if you used `else if`.

Comment: @Barmar Yea your right I was just about to update the question regarding that.

Comment: Comparing floats for equality can be tricky. Watch out for that. You don't need a for loop, but some maths to populate the vec2.

Comment: @NeilKirk They're not really floats, since he uses `floor` when assigning it.

Comment: Good point I'll convert to int.

Comment: in the pattern there is a `.2` missing... 6 -> .4, 7 -> 0, where as in all other steps the value is reduced by .2, is that correct

Comment: Yeah, I was just wondering the same thing. It makes my numerical solution harder, since the formula is different depending on where in the scale the value is.

Comment: No that was a typo. sorry

Comment: What about this. I didn't test it as I'm very tired. `TextureCoord = vec2(fmod(((22.0 - positionInTime) * 0.2), 1.0), floor(((22.0 - positionInTime) * 0.2) / 5.0));`

Comment: The pattern still isn't consistent. The second coordinates start out in groups of 5 with the same value, but there are only 4 with `0.6` and 3 with `0.8`.

Comment: @NeilKirk I'm getting "fmod": no matching overloaded function found when testing

Comment: @Barmar what if the sprite sheet had 25 sprites then the pattern would be more consistent. Would that make things easier?

Comment: Probably because it is mixing double literals and floats. `TextureCoord = vec2(fmod(((22.0f - positionInTime) * 0.2f), 1.0f), floor(((22.0f - positionInTime) * 0.2f) / 5.0f));`

Comment: It's your pattern, you tell me. I'm trying to understand if there's supposed to be a pattern or the values are more arbitrary.

Comment: @Barmar the vectors are just the positions of the sprites. So I think having 5 rows of 5 would be better then 2 in the last row. But I'm having trouble coming up with any thing so If I need to change things to get a solution that's cool

Comment: @NeilKirk the 22.0f is unsupported. I'm using OpenGL ES 2.0. and because it's WebGL I think it has to support version 1.0.

Comment: I don't know anything about those, only C++.

Comment: @NeilKirk Yea GLSL has basically the same syntax it's just that floating-point suffix's were unsupported until version 3.0

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help. Problem solved.

Comment: FYI: It's not normal to hard code sprite sheets in your shader. It's also likely really slow. Of course do what you want, just passing on info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can change to a simple pattern of 5x5, this will calculate it in Javascript:

```
var x = ((25 - positionInTime) % 5) / 5.0;
var y = Math.floor((25 - positionInTime) / 5) / 10.0;
TextureCoord = vec2(x, y);
```

If not, you can use:

```
if (positionInTime > 22) {
    var x = 0;
    var y = 0;
if (positionInTime > 7) {
    x = ((22 - positionInTime) % 5) / 5.0;
    y = Math.floor((22 - positionInTime) / 5) / 10.0;
} else {
    x = ((7 - positionInTime) % 4) / 5.0;
    y = Math.floor((7 - positionInTime) / 5) / 10.0;
}
TextureCoord = vec2(x, y);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have been playing around with the first example and it's almost working perfectly. The only thing is I think it's giving me values in-between what I'm looking for. Is it possible to have it round to the closest of these values 0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, or 0.8.

Comment: I'm not sure why it's giving you values in between. When you calculate `positionInTime`, you're rounding it to an integer. Note that these values don't have an exact representation in binary floating point, so there will be a little bit of error. But if you display them with only 1 decimal digit, it should round off properly.

Comment: Just realized that I was dividing by 10, but it should be 5.

Comment: Cool i'll convert from float to int. There's no console log in GLSL so it's kinda tricky to trouble shoot.

Comment: awsome I'll adjust that as well

Comment: It might be best to multiply everything by 10 when you're doing the calculations, so everything is integers.

Comment: I just divided the value by 5 and everything is working great. Thanks for the help. It is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can create array of vec2 and use rounded positionInTime as index of this array without loop.

You can also to calculate each vector, but if values have regularity. The following code is in doubt:

```
if ( positionInTime == 7.0) {
   TextureCoord = vec2( 0.0, 0.6 ); 
}
if ( positionInTime == 6.0) {
   TextureCoord = vec2( 0.4, 0.6 ); 
}
```

I think there is an error (0.4 instead of 0.2).